# How to roll back Oracle transactions you no longer have control over

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions

I've been developing a shell script that runs some Oracle queries, but I've had to kill it a few times, leaving orphaned, uncommitted transactions pending. Now, I can't run update statements anymore because of those pending transactions. How do I fix them? Can I do anything myself or do I have to contact a DBA?

Comment: you have to kill the previous session .. for that you can contact dba..

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of transaction you're attempting?

Comment: @RobB, just something very simple: "update WELL_MASTER set REMARK='test' where WELL_UWI='50023100060000';". Nothing mission critical.